# Synonym of 'continue'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Here is my sentence:

> **Continue the execution** with a fixed number of resources generates a delay and an additional overhead in terms of performance.

How can I change 'continue' ?

By execution I mean "running application"

Comment: What research have you done? Have you consulted a dictionary/thesaurus? Please edit into your OP this information, and why you are not satisfied with what that research has indicated, or your question is likely to be put on hold or closed as General Reference (GR).

Comment: You mean *continu**ing*** the execution.

Comment: Yes, but i'd like to change it. i find in thesarus 'Progressing'

Comment: As Little Eva suggested, you can [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/245369/edit) your post and include that information, and reasoning why the word "progressing" doesn't work for you. That will make it easier for others to think of the right word for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can effectively replace "continue" (or, Kris' suggestion, *continuing*) with the verb, "proceed" (or, its gerund, "*proceeding*")

> **proceed** *verb*: gerund or present participle: **proceeding**: begin or continue a course of action. "we can *proceed* with our investigation"
>
> *synonyms*: begin, make a start, get going, move, set something in motion.
>
> • move forward, especially after reaching a certain point. "the ship could *proceed* to Milwaukee"
>
> *synonyms*: go, make one's way, advance, move, progress, carry on, press on, push on. "he proceeded down the road" See Google [**proceed**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=proceeding+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=proceeding+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i7i30l4.0.0.2.1456326...........0.WezZMHHFXZI&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score -1):

Resume

*Resuming the execution with a fixed number of resources generates a delay and an additional overhead in terms of performance.*

Comment: *Resuming* is **not** a synonym of *continuing.*